# How to group by AND annotate MODELS with django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have this:

```
class City(models.Model):
      postal_code = models.IntegerField()

class CountryViewset(GenericViewSet, ListModelMixin, RetrieveModelMixin):
    queryset = City.objects.values("country_code").annotate(cities_ids=ArrayAgg("id"))
    serializer_class = CountrySerializer

class CountrySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    country_code = serializers.IntegerField()
    cities_ids = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.IntegerField())
```

I got:

```
{
    country_code: 1,
    cities_ids: [1, 2, 3],
}
```

Is it possible to annotate objects directly ?
I want my Country queryset to look like this:

```
<Queryset [
  {
    country_code: 1,
    cities_ids: <QuerySet [<City: 1>, <City: 2>, <City: 3>]>,
  },
  ...
]>
```

Because for the future I will add a lot of django filters and I don't want to get/filter City objects everytime I do operations for performance purposes.

I cannot create Country Model because I'm not allowed to use manage command to sync regularly Country models.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how that affects filtering?

Answer (score 0):

> Because for the future I will add a lot of django filters and I don't want to get/filter City objects everytime I do operations for performance purposes.

I'm not really following how that affects filtering `City` objects. Your queryset takes `City` as "root model". You can use:

```
class CountryViewset(GenericViewSet, ListModelMixin, RetrieveModelMixin):
    queryset = City.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CountrySerializer

    def filter_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return (
            super()
            .filter_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
            .values('country_code')
            .annotate(cities_ids=ArrayAgg('id'))
        )
```

that means that it will first pass through Django's filtering backend, and then you thus annotate and post-process the queryset. So if you later plug in a `FilterSet`, it will use that filterset.

That being said, I think the modeling is likely the problem. You normally should have a `Country` model, perhaps with `code` as primary key, and work with `Foreignkey`s.